# Working with Data from csv file

Tags: c#

I have a large CSV file (50000 * 25) which is essentially a data table that has numeric and alphanumeric fields.

I have used "A Fast CSV Reader" from Lumenworks on code project. (link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader?msg=4600509#xx4600509xx)

I m looking for the most efficient way to work with the data later, I will have to sum, average etc over parts of the data.

My code so far:

```
static void Main()
    {
        // open the file "data.csv" which is a CSV file with headers
        using (CsvReader csv =
               new CsvReader(new StreamReader(@"c:\Temp\Extrinsic_Hourly.csv"), true))
        {
            int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
            csv.SupportsMultiline = false;

            List<string> filedata = new List<string>();
            string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();



            while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)        
                {
                //if (headers[i] == "PowerPrice")
                    filedata.Add(csv[i]);
                }
            }


            File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\Temp\test.txt", filedata); 


        }
```

The last line is just to check that import worked. This works fine and is relatively fast but now I have this huge list and it is difficult to work with. If I now need to average over column 13 I m stuck how to do this.

```
filedata.column(13).Average()
```

obviously doesnt work, not least because its all strings.

It would be nicer to import the data more structured into a class, or convert entire columns of the big 2-d list into 1d lists upon which I could also convert strings into doubles if they are numeric.

Any ideas what the best way is if I have to later perform arithmitic operations on entire columns or part of a column based on criteria from a different column, for instance column 1 has the date and I might want to sum column 2 by months.

Thanks.

Comment: so you are suggesting making a custom class and then on import convert already to date, string, double etc and then it would be easy to work with. Or do you think its faster to import all as string and then convert from the large list? thanks

Comment: It is better to convert each record when you read it since it saves a lot of memory. Think for example to the number 123456, if you store it as string it occupied at least 3 times the memory of the same information stored as integer...

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward approach would be to use a `DataTable`. For example:

```
DataTable tblCSV = new DataTable("CSV");
var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fullPath);
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437); // use the correct encoding
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fullPath, encoding))
{
    //reader.ReadLine(); // skip all lines but header+data
    Char quotingCharacter = '\0';//'"';
    Char escapeCharacter = quotingCharacter;
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, true, Importer.FieldDelimiter, quotingCharacter, escapeCharacter, '\0', ValueTrimmingOptions.All))
    {
        csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ParseError;
        csv.DefaultParseErrorAction = ParseErrorAction.RaiseEvent;
        csv.ParseError += csv_ParseError;
        csv.SkipEmptyLines = true;
        try
        {
            // load into DataTable
            tblCSV.Load(csv, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, csvTable_FillError);
```

Then you can use Linq-To-DataSet:

```
double avg = tblCSV.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => int.Parse(r.Field<string>(13)))
    .Average();
```

Comment: Just remember that DataTable objects have a big memory footprint and *maybe* for this amount of data it should be better to create specialized lightweight (list?) structures that could be handled with parallel algorithms.

Comment: It turns out that for the files I have to work with the datatable really slows it down and I load it to a custom class now. Thanks though!